# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions for two separate app

Tags: firebase

I get this error message:

`Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

I know that this comes with configuration of rule of Firebase.

My current firebase rule is below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I use this firebase DB with mobile app and I use `phone verification` authorization of Firebase.

That's why my rule should be `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`.

But I also use this same DB with web site.

In my web site, I don't want to use authorization, I want to have my own login process.

But if so, I can't get data values from DB due to this rule.

I get this error message: **Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.**

So if I change this rule to below,

```
  allow read, write: if true;
```

Then my mobile app is not properly working.

In this case, How can I set my rule for both usage?

Should I have authorization process of firebase also in web site?

Comment: To understand better, do you want to authenticate the users on mobile with phone number, while on the website, you don't want any sort of authentication?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes right

Comment: Ok, but why would you do that?

Comment: "I want to have my own login process" What is your login process?

Comment: @AlexMamo - I will create user account on my own manually on Database, but if so, I can't proceed email verification to create account.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec -  I will create user account on my own manually on Database, but if so, I can't proceed email verification to create account.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Renaud asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way with Firebase security rules to limit access based on what device is used to access the data. The rules that you specify apply to all users, no matter what device they log in from.

The only option I can think of is to secure access to your database, and then create an endpoint on Cloud Functions or Cloud Run to serve as the access point for your web users. Such an endpoint runs in a trusted environment, which means it bypasses security rules and can thus return the data to the (anonymous) web users.